# Best time for Mediterranean cruise

Tags: cruising, mediterranean

Has anyone done a Mediterranean cruise? If so, what is the best time to go during the year? We are thinking either May or September.

Comment: Hi Coder, Welcome to Travel.SE.  Please have a look at our [FAQ], as something we try to focus on is not asking questions which cannot be answered objectively.  As your question stands it doesn't meet our criteria and would need to be closed - however you can edit and update it still and if it's closed by then, we'll reopen it.  'Best time to go' - for what? For the heat? Or lack of crowds? Or lower prices? Or for festivals? Currently it's a bit vague - if you could give more information about what you're after, then we can seek out the information for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to provide a general-applicable answer to this broad questions:

From April to November you will have the widest selection of cruise ships. End of October the holiday season in Europe comes to an end and a lot of small cruise lines and tourist locations in the whole Mediterranean sea just shut down. Note that a few cruise lines operate in the Mediterranean year round. So cruise ships will be available nevertheless during the winter. From June to August it is the high season. Prices are the highest then.

The temperatures during the summer can really be very hot. It is not uncommon to reach almost 40 degrees even on the ocean. On the other hand, in winter the temperatures are sometimes so low that you can go outside without a jacket and you can't really enjoy the sea. So the best time based on the temperatures is in the spring and autumn.